# PHP HTML Tags and Formatting

Tags: php

Ok, I have a very odd problem occurring.

This is the text I have in the database:

```
<p>Test for formatting text</p>
<p>test</p> 
<hr>This problem has NOT occurred previously.
```

This echos out fine on the php page with all formatting intact without any extra work.

However, when I use `mail()` to send a notification, the text comes out like this:

```
pTestforformattingtextpptestphrThisproblemhasNOToccurredpreviously
```

I've tried `htmlentities()` with no luck.

Email headers used:

```
$headers = "From: xyz <xyz@xyz.com> \n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Exactly what do you expect us to be able to do? Since you haven't provided any code, and just some symptoms, at best we can pat you on your head and go "there there, it'll get better eventually".

Comment: There's no related code to provide... I said when I echo the text with that formatting it works. When it's included in an email, it provides the tags as just letters and with no spaces. Maybe somebody has encountered the same problem and can help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the header parameter:

```
mail("asdf@asdf.com", "subject", "<i>Hello</i>", 
     "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

---

You need to also specify the Mime before the content type and add the `"\r\n";`:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xyz <xyz@xyz.com>' . "\r\n";
```